# Oracle Provider not found - A different confusion

Tags: oracle, vbscript

I have a vba code to connect to oracle like below

```
cn.Open ( _
"User ID=ABC" & _
";Password=ABCDE" & _
";Data Source=PROD" & _
";Provider=MSDAORA.1")
```

When I execute this therough vba macro it's working. But when i execute the same provider 'MSDAORA.1' through vbscript file, it's showing 'provider not found'. How is this possible. Please suggest me a solution.

Thanks

Comment: Are you saying that you are trying to run it as a separate external .vbs file and it is failing?

Comment: yes...it's  failing when i run a separate .vbs file

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to run it 64 bit... Don't think that will work. You could try running the 32bit cscript.exe? Or register a 64bit Ora client.